# Do you know a way to protect the JS code and make it visible only if requested by the remote?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Theoretically JS runs in the browser, then after the first download can be easily copied and made to run directly from the local, without going through the remote server. Because I need to sell an application * js (pay-as-you-use) I need to check each request and make it available ONLY if required by that particular site and, of course, only if he paid.

Comment: Do you want them to run it offline? Or are you worried that they will be able to circumvent you pay-as-you-go structure?

Comment: no, always online. It will embedded on their web site. I worried about my "pay-as-you-go" structure..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work. As soon as someone downloaded a copy of the JavaScript file, he or she can always save a copy of it and even redistribute it.

Thus you cannot protect the JavaScript itself - but assuming you rely on some client-server interaction (i.e. AJAX), the server would not respond to requests coming from non-authorized sources, thus rendering the client-side worthless.

If you need to protect your business logic, don't put it into JavaScript. Alternatively, sue everybody who uses your scripts without having obtained a license (not sure if this is practical, though ...).

Comment: Ok, but on my remote server how could i recognize an "non-authorized sources". I mean if a bad user copy script locally, the key will be the same...

Comment: What about a whitelist of source domains? But whatever you do, it will just make access to the script more difficult, but never impossible.

Comment: Suing is not practical, but it's very easy to publish a list of people who violate your terms of use, which will likely appear when anyone googles the end-user company name. it's really unlikely that anyone who's actually got something to lose would not pay you. And people who *don't* have anything to lose probably wouldn't have paid you anyway, if there had been some way to restrict use. In reality, any substantive commercial user is likely to pay you, why risk that over a few bucks? And anyone who doesn't pay you is probably not a lost sale.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't make the JS file that you plan to sell available directly on a URL like

```
yourdomain.com/yourfile.js
```

I would offer it on a URL like

```
yourdomain.com/getfile
```

Where /getfile is a URL that is processed by a PHP/Java etc server-side language where you can check whatever credentials you need to check, be it requesting domain name, IP address, some token or something else.

Comment: None of which will stop anyone from just saving the script when their browser loads it while accessing any web site which uses it. There is no way to effectively protect javascript.

Comment: True but if he is selling his script to other website owners then his TOS can state that they must link to the script on his server.

Comment: For what purpose? That only makes life harder for the end user and the seller (who must now ensure his server/bandwidth/etc is adequate for this purpose, and suddenly he has to worry about being an ISP). At the same time it has no effect on limiting unauthorized use.

Comment: It doesn't make life harder for anyone at all. A benefit being that he can release updates transparently and optionally control users (being remote website owners) purchasing upgrades to the script. He never will stop someone stealing the script same as you cant stop people taking images from a site but I don't think that is the point here.

Comment: It's exactly what he said the point was, in his comment on the OP. Releasing updates transparently is not a benefit to anyone using an embedded script, unless it is truly an island unto itself. Can you imagine if your site updated jQuery versions every time they had a new release? Half the internet would have broken on 1.6. Nobody's that good a programmer, that there are no possible consequences. It certainly makes life harder for him too. What if his ISP went down? All his customer's web sites go down. He's got to pay for all that bandwidth, too. One more headache, why?

Answer (score 1):

if your application is made in java you can use a ServletFilter to check if the request is valid (if the IP is correct, or maybe you can use a ticket like the facebook, twitter, whatyouwant rest API), and if isn't valid don't show nothing

if you aren't using java I think that something similar can be made with every programming language

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little more trouble than it's worth. Yes, you could require clients to provide a token and whitelist certain domains, etc. But they can still open *any* site that uses that particular JavaScript -- even someone else's -- and just Save As... .

A better bet is controlling the script's interaction with your server. If it makes any AJAX calls a server you control, *then* take that chance to authenticate. If it doesn't depend on data from you in that way, I think you'll just have to face the problem that anyone dedicated enough *will* be able to download your script and *will* be able to use it with a little bit of playing around.

Your best bet is, in addition to the above, keep track of domains that have paid and search every once in a while to find if anyone's taking your code.